# Avoid ConnectionTimeoutError when pool size is smaller than number of threads

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

Can I reliably have a connection pool size smaller than the number of threads which are concurrently using ActiveRecord connections?  I want the thread pool size to be one.

I am getting error:

```
could not obtain a database connection within 5.000       
conds (waited 5.000 seconds) ActiveRecord::ConnectionTimeoutError)
```

I'm trying to simulate it my local machine. but here also I'm facing the same error.

```
@db_host  = "localhost"
@db_user  = "root"
@db_pass  = "root"
@db_name = "me_dev1"

ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(  
:adapter => "mysql2",  
:host => @db_host,  
:database => @db_name,  
:pool     => 1,
:reaping_frequency => 1
)  

class Test < ActiveRecord::Base  
   def create_data

      100.times do |i|
        t1=Thread.new {
         begin
          test=Test.where(:test_name => "automation test")
          puts test
         ensure
          ActiveRecord::Base.connection.close if ActiveRecord::Base.connection ;
          ActiveRecord::Base.clear_active_connections! ;
        end
     }
    t1.join
   end
   end 
end 

Test.new.create_data
```

Thanks

Comment: I have taken the liberty of editing your question to make the title and question more specific.  If I have erred and caused your question to no longer be accurate, would you please roll back my edit?

Answer (score 2):

ActiveRecord uses a separate connection for each thread.  The reliable way to make this code work is to make the pool size greater than or equal to the number of threads.

If you want to have a smaller pool size than the number of threads, you should increase the amount of time that ActiveRecord waits to get a connection out of the pool.  This is done with the `checkout_timeout` option, e.g.:

```
ActiveRecord::Base.establish_connection(  
  ...
  checkout_timeout: 3_600,    # wait an hour
)
```